# How can I receive a hex data from serial port and display it in a textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, hex

I use the following

```
byte[] hex=new byte[1000];
string RecievedData = myport.ReadExisting();
if (!(RecievedData == ""))
{
    hex = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(RecievedData);
    string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(hex);
    txtbox.text+=hexString;
}
```

but problem is that this code converts all bytes that do not have a     character value to 0x3F.

Comment: Is it WPF, Winforms or Asp.net?

Comment: 0x3F == '?'.  That happens when you use ReadExisting() on binary data, byte values >= 0x80 do not have a corresponding ASCII character so they produce a question mark.  You must read binary data with the Read() method.